# Waiting until all promises have resolved while recursively walking a directory

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I'm trying to recursively walk a directory tree and gather all the file names. In the following code, however, the `console.log()` at the end runs too early, not waiting for the promises generated by the function's recursive `cacheDir` call to resolve:

```
function cacheDir(dir) {
  return fs.readdir(dir).then(items => {
    const readDirPromises = []

    for (let item of items) {
      const fullPath = path.join(dir, item)
      const lstat = fs.lstat(fullPath)
      readDirPromises.push(lstat)

      lstat.then(stats => {
        if (stats.isFile()) {
          return fullPath
        } else {
          return cacheDir(fullPath)
        }
      })
    }

    return Promise.all(readDirPromises)
  })
}

cacheDir("../someDir/")
  .then(results => console.log('done!', results))
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems to me that `readDirPromises` will be an array of  `strings` and promises, each promise of which will itself resolve to an array of strings and promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The promise you wait on with `Promise.all()` needs to be `lstat.then()`, not just `lstat`.  Remember that `lstat.then()` returns a new promise and that new promise tracks any promises returned from within the `.then()` handler which you need because of your recursion.

Here's a version that does that (and gets rid of some temporary variables):

```
function cacheDir(dir) {
  return fs.readdir(dir).then(items => {
    const readDirPromises = [];

    for (let item of items) {
      const fullPath = path.join(dir, item);

      readDirPromises.push(fs.lstat(fullPath).then(stats => {
        if (stats.isFile()) {
          return fullPath;
        } else {
          return cacheDir(fullPath);
        }
      }));
    }

    return Promise.all(readDirPromises)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that `then()` returns a new promise!

Comment: @maxedison - That's how promise chaining works.  The newly returned promise waits for any promise returned from the `.then()` and thus you get a chain.